# Azure WebSites and Distributed caching

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-caching

What is the right way to implement azure websites (not webroles) that use distributed caching?
Does Azure have anything built in or a 3-rd party has to be involved?

Edit:

I have been struggling with suggested Windows Azure Caching. The server kept responding with error *ErrorCode<ERRCA0019>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Check the client version. It should be within the allowed version range on the server. If necessary, upgrade the client to the allowed version.*

After looooong search I have stumbled upon this [link](http://www.brandonmartinez.com/2012/11/27/fix-a-check-client-version-error-in-azure-shared-caching/) that fixed it all.

Bottom line, when looking for NuGet package, **DO NOT** use Windows Azure Caching, but [Windows Azure Shared Caching v1.7](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Caching/).

Comment: Just like Abhinav Gupta pointed out, Azure Cache Service is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Azure Cache Service (Preview) has just been released. That is the best way to use distributed caching with Azure Websites.

The Shared Caching service is being deprecated!

Comment: [Windows Azure Cache Service preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/07ef034e-4bfa-4d44-a328-bd13aa1578b2#WhatsNew).

Answer (score 1):

Well the easiest way is to just use [Azure Shared Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh697519.aspx) for distributed caching.  You will have to provision the caching in the Azure Management Portal but then after that the API is pretty straightforward.

Here is a link to the Nuget package for the libraries: [Windows Azure Caching](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching/2.1.0.0)

The prices for distributed caching are pretty outrageous still:  [Azure Cache Pricing](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/caching/)

Comment: I have edited my question with details about solution that did work.